# SQL Server 2008 Management studio tabs text

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there a way to edit the tabs text in the management studio for "Edit X rows" result grid?
When right click a table and select "Edit X rows" (i know that X can be edited) the tab that opens has a big name: "HOST_NAME.DB_NAME - dbo.TABLE_NAME".

for example contrast the highlighted tab ("edit X rows") to the leftmost tab ("select X rows"):
[image]

i am looking for a way to shorten the name of the tab.
I can do it for text queries (Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Editor tab and status bar) but couldn't find how to do it for Edit X rows"

Comment: Do you mean edit the SQL query used to generate the grid?